# Dropping rows with contain of a list of certain strings in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to drop rows which contain certain sub strings in a column. I want to drop all values that contain the sub strings 'Year', 'Monday', '/'

My `dataframe` looks like:

```
col1
24/05/2020
May Year 2020
Monday
May 2020
```

The code I tried:

```
drop_values = ['Monday','Year', '/']
df = df[~df['Col1'].str.contains(drop_values)]
```

However I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: `'|'.join(drop_values)` , join the list and pass into str.contains

Comment: `df[~df['Col1'].str.contains('|'.join(drop_values))]`

Comment: To explain a little further.  You are creating a regular expression from your list using '|'.join where '|' is an OR operator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Series.str.contains` method accepts a regex.

```
>>> df
            col1
0     24/05/2020
1  May Year 2020
2         Monday
3       May 2020
>>> drop_values = ['Monday','Year', '/']
>>> df[~df['col1'].str.contains('|'.join(drop_values))]
       col1
3  May 2020
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
df = df[~df['col1'].str.contains('Monday|Year|/')]
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
       col1
3  May 2020
```